# Heroku postgresql queries not working on Heroku, but work locally

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, heroku

When running locally and connecting to Heroku with the same `DATABASE_URL`, I'm able to connect and query the db perfectly fine.

When the same code is running on Heroku -- the query never returns and will eventually time out.

DB Code:

```
const connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
const pool = new Pool(
    {
        connectionString: connectionString,
        ssl: true
    }
);

public async query(text: any, params: any): Promise<any> {
    return pool.query(text, params);
}
```

This works as expected when I run on localhost and attach to the Heroku Postgres add-on (Hobby tier), but when deployed to Heroku it no longer works. The `DATABASE_URL` is loaded correctly though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird one, but if anyone runs into this problem here was our solution:

We used the `pg` package and were running version `^7.12.1`, which allowed us to connect and query the Heroku hosted database locally, but not when the server was deployed on Heroku.

The fix was updating the `pg` package, which we are now running version `^8.5.1`.

Comment: Thanks, had the same issue and this was it.